# Undeserved reputation.

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

A few moments I edited a question's body while forgetting to edit the title the first edit got approved and so did the second in which I edited the title. I got reputation for both so, shouldn't a user whose edits' get reviewed be only credited for one edit?

Comment: You made two suggested edits, and both were accepted.  That means that the +4 reputation was "deserved" according to the system.  I really wouldn't worry about this: you have probably already seen that you earn way more reputation than (you believe) you really should for some posts, and way less for others. Reputation is certainly not an exact science.

Comment: @Arthur: Reputation is numbers; numbers don't lie; therefore reputation is always true; the truth is well-defined (see Tarski's definition of truth); therefore reputation is exact science. Therefore by Godel's incompleteness theorem there is always reputation that you cannot explain.

Comment: Mea culpa! I approved the first edit, not noticing that the title needed to be changed also.

Comment: had the same n http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650631/a-problem-of-forming-equal-angles-in-plane-geometry, have changed it to a feature request, cannot do that will make new question

Comment: If you feel strongly about it, find a couple answers you don't like and downvote them. You'll lose the extra reputation and help separate wheat from chaff at the same time.

Answer (score 11):

Approved edits really aren't worth enough reputation for it to matter.  I can't see somebody trying to game the system by making tons of consecutive suggested edits.

I'm inclined to say, enjoy your extra 2 reputation, whether or not you believe you deserve it.

Comment: I thought it might have been a bug, thanks for the answer Alexander.

Comment: No problem, @user10444.  Thanks for taking the time to edit.